# Augmented matrices and system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Why are $$[\mathbf{c}_1 \;\mathbf{c}_2]\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2
\end{bmatrix} = \mathbf{b}_1$$ and $$[\mathbf{c}_1 \;\mathbf{c}_2]\begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\ 
y_2
\end{bmatrix} = \mathbf{b}_2$$

equivalent to

$$[\mathbf{c}_1 \;\mathbf{c}_2 : \mathbf{b}_1 \;\mathbf{b}_2]$$

Comment: properties of matrix multiplication, how to solve same system with different inhomogeneous terms...

Comment: I don't understand how that is accomplished unfortunately...

Comment: What system of equations does the notation $[\mathbf{c}_1 \;\mathbf{c}_2 : \mathbf{b}_1 \;\mathbf{b}_2]$ represent? If you understand that notation, you should be able to see why it's equivalent to the other two equations.

Answer (score 1):

So, in your expression 
$$
[\mathbf{c}_1 \;\mathbf{c}_2]
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2
\end{bmatrix} = 
\mathbf{b}_1
$$
I assume that $\mathbf c_1,\mathbf c_2, \mathbf b_1, \mathbf b_2$ are column vectors, and that 
$$
[\mathbf{c}_1 \;\mathbf{c}_2 : \mathbf{b}_1 \;\mathbf{b}_2]
$$
is an augmented matrix with the columns described above.  Assuming all of that is correct then, we proceed as follows:

---

The key insight here is that given the matrices
$$
C=[\mathbf{c}_1 \;\mathbf{c}_2]\quad A=[\mathbf v_1, \mathbf v_2]
$$
We have
$$
CA=[C\mathbf v_1,C\mathbf v_2]
$$
Which you should verify by going through the process of matrix multiplication.  With that in mind, we note that putting the matrix
$$
[\mathbf{c}_1 \;\mathbf{c}_2 : \mathbf{b}_1 ]
$$
Into rref (reduced row echelon form) gives the solution set to
$$
[\mathbf{c}_1 \;\mathbf{c}_2]
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2
\end{bmatrix} = 
\mathbf{b}_1
$$
However, all we're doing when we put the matrix into rref is multiplying on the left by a series of elementary matrices.  Adding the column $\mathbf b_2$ does not change what those elementary matrices are, and the resulting entries in that column are the same as those in the last column when we reduce
$$
[\mathbf{c}_1 \;\mathbf{c}_2 : \mathbf{b}_2 ]
$$